# Highest date from hive table with string data type

Tags: hive

I am a newbie to hive and need your help. My requirement is to get the highest date from the table and my date datatype is string. I tried with max(), but it's not working for string data type... please help me on this.

Comment: What's the string format? show some sample data maybe.

Comment: 20150908 (yyyyMMdd) is the format of my date column and is created as string data type in the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use built-in date functions [unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions).

The `unix_timestamp` covert a `string date` to `unix_timestamp` as `int`, which is comparable.

Assume your table name is `t` and the time column is `tt`.

`select max(unix_timestamp(tt, 'yyyyMMdd')) from t` 
would find the max `unix_timestamp` for you, which is the latest date

Comment: Hi this worked for me: select max(cast (cpd_dt as int)) from table limit 1

Comment: Well, in your case this may work. But what if the time format is something like `2015-09-08`

Answer (score 1):

You're asserting the `MAX` doesn't work on Strings in Hive, but in fact it does:

```
Select MAX(dt) FROM (Select explode(Array("20150103", "20150102")) as dt) a;
```

As long as your date string is in a format which can be sorted lexographically, `MAX` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since 0.12.0 version max(date) will just work.

If all the values in that column match the pattern 'yyyy-mm-dd' the above syntax should do the job